# Python Pandas: Select Unique from df based on Rule

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe (originally generated from a sql query) that looks like:

```
index      AccountId     ItemID    EntryDate
1             100          1000     1/1/2016
2             100          1000     1/2/2016
3             100          1000     1/3/2016
4             101          1234     9/15/2016
5             101          1234     9/16/2016
etc....
```

I'd like to get this whittled down to a unique list, returning only the entry with the earliest date available, something like this:

```
index      AccountId     ItemID    EntryDate
1             100          1000     1/1/2016
4             101          1234     9/15/2016
etc....
```

Any pointers or direction for a fairly new pandas dev? The unique function doesn't appear to be able to handle these types of rules, and looping through the array and working out which one to drop seems like a lot of trouble for a simple task... Is there a function that I'm missing that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `groupby`, `idxmin`, and `.loc`:

```
df_out = df2.loc[df2.groupby('AccountId')['EntryDate'].idxmin()]

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
       AccountId  ItemID  EntryDate
index                              
1            100    1000 2016-01-01
4            101    1234 2016-09-15
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you so much.